# Custom Widget with Transparent Background Showing White

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to follow along with the Flutter udacity course and in this portion of the code, I need to create a custom widget with a transparent background but instead it is showing a white background. The parent background is set to a slightly transparent green and i am using `Scaffold` in the parent widget. How do I get the background of my custom **Category Widget** transparent?

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unit_converter/category.dart';

const _categoryName = 'Cake';
const _categoryIcon = Icons.cake;
const _categoryColor = Colors.green;


void main() => runApp(UnitConverterApp());


class UnitConverterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Unit Converter',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        body: Center(
          child: Category(
              name: _categoryName,
              color: _categoryColor,
              iconLocation: _categoryIcon,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**category.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Category extends StatelessWidget {


  final String name;
  final ColorSwatch color;
  final IconData iconLocation;


  static const _height = 100.0;
  static const _radius = _height / 2;
  static const _padding = 8.0;
  static const _iconSize = 60.0;
  static const _textSize = 24.0;
  static const _iconPadding = 16.0;

  const Category({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.iconLocation,
  })  : assert(name != null),
        assert(color != null),
        assert(iconLocation != null),
        super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          height: _height,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(_padding),
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_radius),
                splashColor: color,
                highlightColor: color,
                onTap: () => print('I was tapped!'),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(_iconPadding),
                        child: Icon(
                            iconLocation,
                            size: _iconSize,
                        ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        name,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set Material  `color: Colors.transparent,` instead of Container

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        height: _height,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(_padding),
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_radius),
            splashColor: color,
            highlightColor: color,
            onTap: () => print('I was tapped!'),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(_iconPadding),
                  child: Icon(
                    iconLocation,
                    size: _iconSize,
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    name,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was driving me crazy. I was staring at this so long I didn't even realize that the solution to the lab on github had it that way as well. Thanks for the extra set of eyes.